# Can we change gradle plugin version in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

My Android studio is 1.5.1 and I found 1.3.0 and 1.5.0 in

> /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle

But I'd like to user gradle plugin 1.1.0, 
I changed the gradle version in build.gradle. But it is userless, so how can I change the gradle plugin version?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The standard way is to go to "File/Project Structure":

[image]

and then to set your plugin configuration in the "Project" section of the window that opens:

[image]

(You can also directly modify your gradle files).

Comment: but in the path /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle, plugin 1.1.0 is not exist

Comment: @chefish You must have a more recent version available in that case. It is best to upgrade when an update is available anyway. Should you absolutely need the 1.1.0, you'll have to install it first.

Answer (score 4):

**Each project** (but you can force each module) can use a **different version**.

You can define the plugin inside the `build.gradle` file in the project (root level, or inside the module).

For example:

```
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
```

Otherwise you can use the menu in:

```
File -> Project Structure -> Project.
```

It will edit automatically the same `build.gradle` file.

Answer (score 1):

**Easy way

Just Open Gradle -> wrapper and change vercion to 5.5.1 and delete gradle -wrapper.jar and run Your Project

---